# Passing a parameter to route in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get details of a particular patient based on id. I want when the id link is clicked to be navigated to a page with details of that patient.

app.routing.modules

```
 {path : 'patients:id', component :PatientDetailsComponent,}
```

patiencomponent.html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Patient's ID</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  <a [routerLink]="['/patients', element.id]"> {{element.id}}</a> </td>
          </ng-container>
```

userservice.ts

```
getPatientDetailsById(id: string ):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this.apiUrl+ id)
  }
```

patientDetailsComponent.ts

```
    export class PatientDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
      patient!: Patient;
    
      constructor(private userService: UserService,
        private router: Router,
         private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        const id=this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
       
        this.userService.getPatientDetailsById(id).subscribe(
          patient=>{
            this.patient= patient;
          }
        )
        
      }

}
```

patient.ts

```
export class Patient {
  id!: string; 
  fullname!: string;
  address!:string;
   
  }
```

Can anyone help  please

Comment: you are missing the forward slash after patient in  `path : 'patients/:id'`

Answer (score 0):

u shoud add / before the id params :

```
{path : 'patients/:id', component :PatientDetailsComponent,}
```

in the service : if the url not end with the "/" do like that

```
getPatientDetailsById(id: string ):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this.apiUrl+"/"+ id)
  }
```

NB : if you need to pass other params :

```
{
   path:'edit/:param1/:param2',component:SomeComponent
   }
```